# Question Classification (Input Classification) using python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, svm, text-classification

I have 4 categories of Questions

1. Casual Questions
2. Personality Questions
3. General Knowledge Questions
4. Doctor Questions

I have a training questions for all of them (maybe 500 questions for each categories). I want to classify the user's input (or the Question) with respect to these 4 Categories on the basis of training data.

What would be the best way to do that? I looked up and found many ways to perform it. I am looking for the way that works the best with more accuracy.

P.S: Very short explanation with a short sample code would be helpful if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Different classification methods have their pros and cons, and within your description it's pretty hard to tell which is more suitable. The best solution is to try them all and find out yourself!

Comment: SO is for programming related questions. You will get better response if you ask similar question on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. I am thinking to try using Support Vector Machines as I guess it would become a good fit or Multinominial Logistic Regression would work? Sorry, pretty new to Python World.